# jax-ws document style and php client

Tags: php, jax-ws, document, soap-client

I created WebService Endpoint using jax-ws. I would like to connect it call it from php client. Php client is not big deal, wrote with SoapClient class.
Everything works fine when im using RPC style. 
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC, use=Use.LITERAL)

But my goal is to use Document style and when i'll change method signature to 
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT, use=Use.LITERAL)

im not receiving any input parameters. Web Service is called properly but params all params are null. Im wondering if this is problem of PHP client or bad configuration on JAX-WS endpoint.
I as using this (http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example-document-style/) tutorial to make JAX-WS enpoint. 
To be honest not much thing to make something wrong, so i think it can be something with php.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple client in Java, use some ide functionalities or command line wsinport, to generate the client, if it will work correctly than the problem is with the client.

Comment: I think we found solution, and it was with namespaces. im sorry for disturbing, but we were a bit crazy with these errors. best regards.